# Number of Shots always 1024/or nothing (IBM q experience)

Tags: ibm-q-experience

I have been running some simple "Hello Quantum World" code and every time I try to run it on 4096 shots or 8192 shots, the results always show as if I ran the code on 1024 shots (or in the most recent case, nothing at all). Is this a bug?

I have only been using the interface (as you can see). In this case, I ran a hadamard gate and then an x gate on 4096 shots. Notice how the shots are not written at all.
Also, I have run other code with just the hadamard gate and then a target gate on 4096 and 8192 shots, but the interface says I ran it on 1024.

[image]